# How to ban access Laravel file from other IP, just allow localhost can access

Tags: php, laravel, apache

OS: Microsoft Windows Server

web server: Apache

front-end framework: Vue.js

back-end framework: Laravel

I set when path is "example.com", I can see my Vue.js page; When path is "example.com:9999", I can see my Laravel project.

I want access to "example.com" from any IP and "example.com:9999" just can access from this website, how to do that?

This is my httpd-vhost.conf.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Apache24\htdocs\index"
    ServerName example.com
    <Directory "C:\Apache24\htdocs\index"> 
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:9999>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Apache24\htdocs\Laravel_project_name\public"
    ServerName example.com
    <Directory "C:\Apache24\htdocs\Laravel_project_name\public"> 
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My final goal is I don't want anyone know what framework I'm using. and prohibit anyone can see my laravel index.php and other file in laravel_project_name/public.

Comment: So you want people to access Vue.js but not Laravel? Is your Vue.js application communicates with Laravel? If so your Laravel application has to be accessible from outside. Because Vue.js will work in visitors' browsers and their browsers will send requests to fetch data from back-end.

Comment: Yes, my vue.js application will call API from my Laravel. So I have to allow every host access of my Laravel because my Vue.js application is allow every host to connect?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [documentation for VirtualHost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost):

> ```
> <VirtualHost addr[:port] [addr[:port]] ...> ... </VirtualHost>
> ```
>
> Addr can be any of the following, optionally followed by a colon and a
> port number (or *):
>
> - The IP address of the virtual host;
> - A fully qualified domain name for the IP address of the virtual host (not recommended);
> - The character *, which acts as a wildcard and matches any IP address.
> - The string *default*, which is an alias for *

If you only want it accessible from localhost, then replace `*` with the localhost IP address.

---

That said, your goal is a bit unclear.

The above will stop a client running on a different computer from accessing on that virtual host.

There's no way to allow users of the Vue application to access that VirtualHost without letting people bypass the Vue application and access it directly. They will still be making an HTTP request to your server and there's no way to tell if it was initiated by your code built into your Vue application or someone else's code (or manually constructed request).

Comment: umm...if I just don't want anyone can access any file in my Laravel/public, not prohibit any host access my Laravel API, how to do that?